# Simple payment form for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, stripe-payments

I'm facing some difficulties in wordpress. I don't know how to code, let's start there.

What I need is a super easy embedded payment form (name, email, credit card and paypal).

[payment form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9Qw.png) (due to the reputation i can't post the image directly)

I'm actually building a simple landing page with one product only, and I need the payment form to be at the bottom of that same landing page.

All the tutorials I've been watching are teaching how to do it when you have a cart and a whole website.

I tried with multiple tutorials and plugins already but none really worked. Woocheckout is among them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try  this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-payment-form/

Comment: Building a direct integration with stripe will require some programming. But there are a lot of third party apps and extensions you can consider in order to enable payments: https://stripe.com/en-ie/partners/apps-and-extensions